# Magento FishPig /wp-admin/ URL 404

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

Just looking for a little bit of help. I have used FishPig on a site I am working on and within the settings all the integration checks are fine.

The only issue is when I go to the dashboard it brings back a 404 for some reason. Also if I was to go direct to the URL (e.g. /wp/wp-admin/) it comes back with an unstyled login page and after logging in, again takes me to a 404. Any ideas?

Magento cache is off and cleared.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An unstyled login page means that your WordPress 'siteurl' option is incorrect. This URL should be the /wp URL. To fix the URL, add the following to the bottom of your wp-config.php file and then refresh the Admin login page:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://www.yoururl.com/wp');
```

Obviously you will need to change http://www.yoururl.com/wp to your actual URL.